# How to switch subframe inside a frameset using Selenium WebDriver.io

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I switch frame 'main', switch frame 'midFrame' is working.
But switch frame 'left' is not working. Please, take a look at the above script?
Thanks,

use lib: http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/frame.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<frameset frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0" rows="80,*,20">
    <frameset frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0" cols="390,*">...</frameset>
    <frame name='main' src="/CorpWeb/IbsJsps/orbilogin.jsp">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <frameset rows="18,22,*" cols="*" ...>
                <frame src'...' name='newMidframe'>...</frame>
                <frame src'...' name='midFrame'>...</frame>
                <frameset rows="245,*" cols="*">
                    <frame src='...' name='left'>...</frame>
                    <frame src='...' name='mainFrame'>...</frame>
                </frameset>
            </frameset>
        </html>
    </frame>
    <frame> ... </frame>    
</frameset>
</html>
```

Error:

> { [RuntimeError: RuntimeError
>        (NoSuchFrame:8) A request to switch to a frame could not be satisfied because the frame could not be found.
>        Problem: no such frame
>
> ```
>  Callstack:
>  -> frame("mainFrame") ]   message: 'RuntimeError\n     (NoSuchFrame:8) A request to switch to a frame could not be satisfied
> ```
>
> because the frame could not be found.\n     Problem: no such
>   frame\u001b[1;30m\n\n     Callstack:\n     -> frame("mainFrame")\n',
>   name: 'RuntimeError',   hasCallStack: true } null { [RuntimeError:
>   RuntimeError
>        (NoSuchFrame:8) A request to switch to a frame could not be satisfied because the frame could not be found.
>        Problem: no such frame
>
> ```
>  Callstack:
>  -> frame("mainFrame") ]   message: 'RuntimeError\n     (NoSuchFrame:8) A request to switch to a frame could not be satisfied
> ```
>
> because the frame could not be found.\n     Problem: no such
>   frame\u001b[1;30m\n\n     Callstack:\n     -> frame("mainFrame")\n',
>   name: 'RuntimeError',   hasCallStack: true }

Comment: Have you tried to use WAIT period before find that frame? I think it is not getting frame because that LEFT frame taking time to load.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that

> **left/mainFrame**
>    both are **not present** under **midFrame**.

To switch to them please switch back to `defaultContent` or `main` frame, and then switch to `left/mainFrame`. You can see in the html tag, **midFrame element ends before next frameset starts**.

Comment: `// Working   
    browser.frame("main",function(err){  
     browser.frame("midFrame",function(err){   
      ...  
 });  
    });`   
   
    `// Not working   
    browser.frame("main",function(err){   
 browser.frame("mainFrame",function(err){  
  ...  
 });  
    });`