# How to navigate a subframe inside a frameset using Selenium WebDriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium

The layout of the hmtl page is the following :

```
<frameset framespacing="0" border="false" frameborder="0" rows="11%,8%,*">
    <frame name="ENTETE" src="fr_entete.htm" scrolling="no" noresize="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">Some elements...</frame>
    <frameset framespacing="0" border="false" frameborder="0" cols="35%,7%,*">
        <frame name="SOMMAIRE" src="fr_sommaire.htm" scrolling="no" noresize="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">Some elements...</frame>
        <frame name="OUTIL" src="fr_outil.htm" scrolling="no" noresize="" marginwidth="2" marginheight="0">Some elements...</frame>
        <frame name="LIBRE" src="fr_libre.asp" scrolling="no" noresize="" marginwidth="2" marginheight="0">Some elements...</frame>
    </frameset>
    <frame name="TRAVAIL" src="cdc_rechgen.asp" scrolling="yes" noresize="" marginwidth="5" marginheight="0" frameborder="0">Some elements...</frame>
</frameset>
```

I need to access to the frame "SOMMAIRE".
This frame is a child of a frameset which is in turn a child of a frameset.
I succeed in navigate to frame "TRAVAIL" and "ENTETE" directly, but I can't succeed in navigate the frame "SOMMAIRE"...

I've tried :

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame("ENTETE")
driver.switch_to.frame("SOMMAIRE")
```

But I always have the following exception :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame
```

I've also read those link, but none of them help me to do what I want...

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732549/python-selenium-webdriver-navigating-nested-frame-sets) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207349/how-to-switch-subframe-inside-a-frameset-using-selenium-webdriver-io) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464808/how-to-navigate-a-subframe-inside-a-frameset-using-selenium-webdriver)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you also add where `iframe` tags are closed? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my post to add where iframe tags are closed.

Answer (score 2):

`SOMMAIRE` frame is not located inside `ENTETE` frame (and, according to the HTML fragment - it is not inside of any frame actually). This means you don't need to switch to `ENTETE` first. Just switch directly to `SOMMAIRE`:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()  # in case you were inside an iframe before
driver.switch_to.frame("SOMMAIRE")
```

Comment: In fact when I go to this html page (made with asp), an input text is (by default) selected in the frame "TRAVAIL". I don't know if it help or not, but I can switch to "ENTETE" frame, but neither to "SOMMAIRE", nor "OUTIL" nor "LIBRE" frames.

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to SOMMAIRE using XPATH

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_SOMMARIE")));
```

Answer (score 0):

User neha bedi seemed to be on the right track but the response needed editing:  Try

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_of_SOMMARIE'))
```

This worked for me.