# Selenium doesn't find elements

Tags: python, selenium, gecko

I'm coding in python with `selenium` `webdriver` to automate some stuff, but `selenium`'s `find_element_*` methods don't work.

These are the webpages I am trying:
https://campus.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/default.do?siteurl=campus&service=10

and

https://webmail.aruba.it/cgi-bin/ajaxmail

and

http://campus.istitutovolta.eu/index.php

I tried all strategies: by_class, by_link, by_name, by_id, ecc.... nothing!! I use gecko and firefox. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
try:
    browser.get("https://campus.webex.com/mw3100/mywebex/default.do?siteurl=campus&service=7")
except:
    print("pagina non trovata")

try:
    utente=browser.find_element_by_name("userName")
except:
    print("elemento non trovato")    
else:
    print(utente)
    utente.send_keys('user@gestione.eu')
try:
    psw=browser.find_element_by_name("PASSWD")
except:
    print("elemento non trovato")    
else:
    print(psw)
    psw.send_keys('123456')
```

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATE 2 + 3:*

**I GOT IT WORK: CHECK IT OUT:**

Variant 1:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
delay = 100  # seconds

# browser.get("https://campus.webex.com/mw3100/mywebex/default.do?siteurl=campus")
browser.get("https://campus.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/login/login.do?siteurl=campus&login_return_url=%2Ftc3300%2Ftrainingcenter%2Fsite%2FinstantSession.do%3Fsiteurl%3Dcampus")

myelem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'mwx-ipt-username')))

utente = browser.find_element_by_id("mwx-ipt-username").send_keys('user@gestione.eu')
```

Variant 2:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
delay = 20  # seconds

browser.get("https://campus.webex.com/mw3100/mywebex/default.do?siteurl=campus")

browser.switch_to.frame("mainFrame")
browser.switch_to.frame("main")

myelem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'mwx-ipt-username')))

utente = browser.find_element_by_id("mwx-ipt-username").send_keys('user@gestione.eu')
```

The problem was the frameset in the site. In parsed [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) html code,
the content of the frames was missing, so synonymous, the login form was not found. This is remedied by a) **variant 1:** You directly open the appropriate frame. b) **variant 2:** you switch from the original page into the frame.

see: [How to navigate a subframe inside a frameset using Selenium WebDriver with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30440887/8980073)

[function for switching frames in python, selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28723274/8980073)

[How to identify and switch to the frame in selenium webdriver when frame does not have id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181195/8980073)

[How to navigate a subframe inside a frameset using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15513308/8980073)

---

*UPDATE:* I will try to find a solution trough the buttons the website provides. Give me some time.

---

I clicked on your link and checked to "userName" and there was no "userName".

It's the same, if you open a new tab in your normal firefox, and type

"[view-source:https://campus.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/default.do?siteurl=campus](http://view-source:https://campus.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/default.do?siteurl=campus)" in it.

I tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
delay = 30  # seconds

try:
    browser.get("https://campus.webex.com/mw3100/mywebex/default.do?siteurl=campus&service=7")
except:
    print("pagina non trovata")

myelem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'mwx-ipt-username')))

try:
    utente = browser.find_element_by_id("mwx-ipt-username")
except:
    print("elemento non trovato")
```

It doesn't work.

The HTML i always get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it-IT">
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name='format-detection' content='telephone=no'>
<meta name='slack-app-id' content='A5P5FDK33'>
<meta name="description" content="5"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicont29.ico" type="image/x-icon">


<script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={xpid:"XQUDUldSGwUCXFdWAAgF"};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,e,n){function r(n){if(!e[n]){var o=e[n]={exports:{}};t[n][0].call(o.exports,function(e){var o=t[n][1][e];return r(o||e)},o,o.exports)}return e[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<n.length;o++)r(n[o]);return r}({1:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){try{s.console&&console.log(t)}catch(e){}}var o,i=t("ee"),a=t(21),s={};try{o=localStorage.getItem("__nr_flags").split(","),console&&"function"==typeof console.log&&(s.console=!0,o.indexOf("dev")!==-1&&(s.dev=!0),o.indexOf("nr_dev")!==-1&&(s.nrDev=!0))}catch(c){}s.nrDev&&i.on("internal-error",function(t){r(t.stack)}),s.dev&&i.on("fn-err",function(t,e,n){r(n.stack)}),s.dev&&(r("NR AGENT IN DEVELOPMENT MODE"),r("flags: "+a(s,function(t,e){return t}).join(", ")))},{}],2:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n,r,s){try{l?l-=1:o(s||new UncaughtException(t,e,n),!0)}catch(f){try{i("ierr",[f,c.now(),!0])}catch(d){}}return"function"==typeof u&&u.apply(this,a(arguments))}function UncaughtException(t,e,n){this.message=t||"Uncaught error with no additional information",this.sourceURL=e,this.line=n}function o(t,e){var n=e?null:c.now();i("err",[t,n])}var i=t("handle"),a=t(22),s=t("ee"),c=t("loader"),f=t("gos"),u=window.onerror,d=!1,p="nr@seenError",l=0;c.features.err=!0,t(1),window.onerror=r;try{throw new Error}catch(h){"stack"in h&&(t(13),t(12),"addEventListener"in window&&t(6),c.xhrWrappable&&t(14),d=!0)}s.on("fn-start",function(t,e,n){d&&(l+=1)}),s.on("fn-err",function(t,e,n){d&&!n[p]&&(f(n,p,function(){return!0}),this.thrown=!0,o(n))}),s.on("fn-end",function(){d&&!this.thrown&&l>0&&(l-=1)}),s.on("internal-error",function(t){i("ierr",[t,c.now(),!0])})},{}],3:[function(t,e,n){t("loader").features.ins=!0},{}],4:[function(t,e,n){function r(){M++,N=y.hash,this[u]=g.now()}function o(){M--,y.hash!==N&&i(0,!0);var t=g.now();this[h]=~~this[h]+t-this[u],this[d]=t}function i(t,e){E.emit("newURL",[""+y,e])}function a(t,e){t.on(e,function(){this[e]=g.now()})}var s="-start",c="-end",f="-body",u="fn"+s,d="fn"+c,p="cb"+s,l="cb"+c,h="jsTime",m="fetch",v="addEventListener",w=window,y=w.location,g=t("loader");if(w[v]&&g.xhrWrappable){var b=t(10),x=t(11),E=t(8),O=t(6),P=t(13),R=t(7),T=t(14),L=t(9),j=t("ee"),S=j.get("tracer");t(15),g.features.spa=!0;var N,M=0;j.on(u,r),j.on(p,r),j.on(d,o),j.on(l,o),j.buffer([u,d,"xhr-done","xhr-resolved"]),O.buffer([u]),P.buffer(["setTimeout"+c,"clearTimeout"+s,u]),T.buffer([u,"new-xhr","send-xhr"+s]),R.buffer([m+s,m+"-done",m+f+s,m+f+c]),E.buffer(["newURL"]),b.buffer([u]),x.buffer(["propagate",p,l,"executor-err","resolve"+s]),S.buffer([u,"no-"+u]),L.buffer(["new-jsonp","cb-start","jsonp-error","jsonp-end"]),a(T,"send-xhr"+s),a(j,"xhr-resolved"),a(j,"xhr-done"),a(R,m+s),a(R,m+"-done"),a(L,"new-jsonp"),a(L,"jsonp-end"),a(L,"cb-start"),E.on("pushState-end",i),E.on("replaceState-end",i),w[v]("hashchange",i,!0),w[v]("load",i,!0),w[v]("popstate",function(){i(0,M>1)},!0)}},{}],5:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){}if(window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&window.performance.getEntriesByType){var o=t("ee"),i=t("handle"),a=t(13),s=t(12),c="learResourceTimings",f="addEventListener",u="resourcetimingbufferfull",d="bstResource",p="resource",l="-start",h="-end",m="fn"+l,v="fn"+h,w="bstTimer",y="pushState",g=t("loader");g.features.stn=!0,t(8);var b=NREUM.o.EV;o.on(m,function(t,e){var n=t[0];n instanceof b&&(this.bstStart=g.now())}),o.on(v,function(t,e){var n=t[0];n instanceof b&&i("bst",[n,e,this.bstStart,g.now()])}),a.on(m,function(t,e,n){this.bstStart=g.now(),this.bstType=n}),a.on(v,function(t,e){i(w,[e,this.bstStart,g.now(),this.bstType])}),s.on(m,function(){this.bstStart=g.now()}),s.on(v,function(t,e){i(w,[e,this.bstStart,g.now(),"requestAnimationFrame"])}),o.on(y+l,function(t){this.time=g.now(),this.startPath=location.pathname+location.hash}),o.on(y+h,function(t){i("bstHist",[location.pathname+location.hash,this.startPath,this.time])}),f in window.performance&&(window.performance["c"+c]?window.performance[f](u,function(t){i(d,[window.performance.getEntriesByType(p)]),window.performance["c"+c]()},!1):window.performance[f]("webkit"+u,function(t){i(d,[window.performance.getEntriesByType(p)]),window.performance["webkitC"+c]()},!1)),document[f]("scroll",r,{passive:!0}),document[f]("keypress",r,!1),document[f]("click",r,!1)}},{}],6:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){for(var e=t;e&&!e.hasOwnProperty(u);)e=Object.getPrototypeOf(e);e&&o(e)}function o(t){s.inPlace(t,[u,d],"-",i)}function i(t,e){return t[1]}var a=t("ee").get("events"),s=t(24)(a,!0),c=t("gos"),f=XMLHttpRequest,u="addEventListener",d="removeEventListener";e.exports=a,"getPrototypeOf"in Object?(r(document),r(window),r(f.prototype)):f.prototype.hasOwnProperty(u)&&(o(window),o(f.prototype)),a.on(u+"-start",function(t,e){var n=t[1],r=c(n,"nr@wrapped",function(){function t(){if("function"==typeof n.handleEvent)return n.handleEvent.apply(n,arguments)}var e={object:t,"function":n}[typeof n];return e?s(e,"fn-",null,e.name||"anonymous"):n});this.wrapped=t[1]=r}),a.on(d+"-start",function(t){t[1]=this.wrapped||t[1]})},{}],7:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n){var r=t[e];"function"==typeof r&&(t[e]=function(){var t=r.apply(this,arguments);return o.emit(n+"start",arguments,t),t.then(function(e){return o.emit(n+"end",[null,e],t),e},function(e){throw o.emit(n+"end",[e],t),e})})}var o=t("ee").get("fetch"),i=t(21);e.exports=o;var a=window,s="fetch-",c=s+"body-",f=["arrayBuffer","blob","json","text","formData"],u=a.Request,d=a.Response,p=a.fetch,l="prototype";u&&d&&p&&(i(f,function(t,e){r(u[l],e,c),r(d[l],e,c)}),r(a,"fetch",s),o.on(s+"end",function(t,e){var n=this;if(e){var r=e.headers.get("content-length");null!==r&&(n.rxSize=r),o.emit(s+"done",[null,e],n)}else o.emit(s+"done",[t],n)}))},{}],8:[function(t,e,n){var r=t("ee").get("history"),o=t(24)(r);e.exports=r,o.inPlace(window.history,["pushState","replaceState"],"-")},{}],9:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){function e(){c.emit("jsonp-end",[],p),t.removeEventListener("load",e,!1),t.removeEventListener("error",n,!1)}function n(){c.emit("jsonp-error",[],p),c.emit("jsonp-end",[],p),t.removeEventListener("load",e,!1),t.removeEventListener("error",n,!1)}var r=t&&"string"==typeof t.nodeName&&"script"===t.nodeName.toLowerCase();if(r){var o="function"==typeof t.addEventListener;if(o){var a=i(t.src);if(a){var u=s(a),d="function"==typeof u.parent[u.key];if(d){var p={};f.inPlace(u.parent,[u.key],"cb-",p),t.addEventListener("load",e,!1),t.addEventListener("error",n,!1),c.emit("new-jsonp",[t.src],p)}}}}}function o(){return"addEventListener"in window}function i(t){var e=t.match(u);return e?e[1]:null}function a(t,e){var n=t.match(p),r=n[1],o=n[3];return o?a(o,e[r]):e[r]}function s(t){var e=t.match(d);return e&&e.length>=3?{key:e[2],parent:a(e[1],window)}:{key:t,parent:window}}var c=t("ee").get("jsonp"),f=t(24)(c);if(e.exports=c,o()){var u=/[?&](?:callback|cb)=([^&#]+)/,d=/(.*)\.([^.]+)/,p=/^(\w+)(\.|$)(.*)$/,l=["appendChild","insertBefore","replaceChild"];f.inPlace(HTMLElement.prototype,l,"dom-"),f.inPlace(HTMLHeadElement.prototype,l,"dom-"),f.inPlace(HTMLBodyElement.prototype,l,"dom-"),c.on("dom-start",function(t){r(t[0])})}},{}],10:[function(t,e,n){var r=t("ee").get("mutation"),o=t(24)(r),i=NREUM.o.MO;e.exports=r,i&&(window.MutationObserver=function(t){return this instanceof i?new i(o(t,"fn-")):i.apply(this,arguments)},MutationObserver.prototype=i.prototype)},{}],11:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){var e=a.context(),n=s(t,"executor-",e),r=new f(n);return a.context(r).getCtx=function(){return e},a.emit("new-promise",[r,e],e),r}function o(t,e){return e}var i=t(24),a=t("ee").get("promise"),s=i(a),c=t(21),f=NREUM.o.PR;e.exports=a,f&&(window.Promise=r,["all","race"].forEach(function(t){var e=f[t];f[t]=function(n){function r(t){return function(){a.emit("propagate",[null,!o],i),o=o||!t}}var o=!1;c(n,function(e,n){Promise.resolve(n).then(r("all"===t),r(!1))});var i=e.apply(f,arguments),s=f.resolve(i);return s}}),["resolve","reject"].forEach(function(t){var e=f[t];f[t]=function(t){var n=e.apply(f,arguments);return t!==n&&a.emit("propagate",[t,!0],n),n}}),f.prototype["catch"]=function(t){return this.then(null,t)},f.prototype=Object.create(f.prototype,{constructor:{value:r}}),c(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(f),function(t,e){try{r[e]=f[e]}catch(n){}}),a.on("executor-start",function(t){t[0]=s(t[0],"resolve-",this),t[1]=s(t[1],"resolve-",this)}),a.on("executor-err",function(t,e,n){t[1](n)}),s.inPlace(f.prototype,["then"],"then-",o),a.on("then-start",function(t,e){this.promise=e,t[0]=s(t[0],"cb-",this),t[1]=s(t[1],"cb-",this)}),a.on("then-end",function(t,e,n){this.nextPromise=n;var r=this.promise;a.emit("propagate",[r,!0],n)}),a.on("cb-end",function(t,e,n){a.emit("propagate",[n,!0],this.nextPromise)}),a.on("propagate",function(t,e,n){this.getCtx&&!e||(this.getCtx=function(){if(t instanceof Promise)var e=a.context(t);return e&&e.getCtx?e.getCtx():this})}),r.toString=function(){return""+f})},{}],12:[function(t,e,n){var r=t("ee").get("raf"),o=t(24)(r),i="equestAnimationFrame";e.exports=r,o.inPlace(window,["r"+i,"mozR"+i,"webkitR"+i,"msR"+i],"raf-"),r.on("raf-start",function(t){t[0]=o(t[0],"fn-")})},{}],13:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n){t[0]=a(t[0],"fn-",null,n)}function o(t,e,n){this.method=n,this.timerDuration=isNaN(t[1])?0:+t[1],t[0]=a(t[0],"fn-",this,n)}var i=t("ee").get("timer"),a=t(24)(i),s="setTimeout",c="setInterval",f="clearTimeout",u="-start",d="-";e.exports=i,a.inPlace(window,[s,"setImmediate"],s+d),a.inPlace(window,[c],c+d),a.inPlace(window,[f,"clearImmediate"],f+d),i.on(c+u,r),i.on(s+u,o)},{}],14:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e){d.inPlace(e,["onreadystatechange"],"fn-",s)}function o(){var t=this,e=u.context(t);t.readyState>3&&!e.resolved&&(e.resolved=!0,u.emit("xhr-resolved",[],t)),d.inPlace(t,y,"fn-",s)}function i(t){g.push(t),h&&(x?x.then(a):v?v(a):(E=-E,O.data=E))}function a(){for(var t=0;t<g.length;t++)r([],g[t]);g.length&&(g=[])}function s(t,e){return e}function c(t,e){for(var n in t)e[n]=t[n];return e}t(6);var f=t("ee"),u=f.get("xhr"),d=t(24)(u),p=NREUM.o,l=p.XHR,h=p.MO,m=p.PR,v=p.SI,w="readystatechange",y=["onload","onerror","onabort","onloadstart","onloadend","onprogress","ontimeout"],g=[];e.exports=u;var b=window.XMLHttpRequest=function(t){var e=new l(t);try{u.emit("new-xhr",[e],e),e.addEventListener(w,o,!1)}catch(n){try{u.emit("internal-error",[n])}catch(r){}}return e};if(c(l,b),b.prototype=l.prototype,d.inPlace(b.prototype,["open","send"],"-xhr-",s),u.on("send-xhr-start",function(t,e){r(t,e),i(e)}),u.on("open-xhr-start",r),h){var x=m&&m.resolve();if(!v&&!m){var E=1,O=document.createTextNode(E);new h(a).observe(O,{characterData:!0})}}else f.on("fn-end",function(t){t[0]&&t[0].type===w||a()})},{}],15:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){var e=this.params,n=this.metrics;if(!this.ended){this.ended=!0;for(var r=0;r<d;r++)t.removeEventListener(u[r],this.listener,!1);if(!e.aborted){if(n.duration=a.now()-this.startTime,4===t.readyState){e.status=t.status;var i=o(t,this.lastSize);if(i&&(n.rxSize=i),this.sameOrigin){var c=t.getResponseHeader("X-NewRelic-App-Data");c&&(e.cat=c.split(", ").pop())}}else e.status=0;n.cbTime=this.cbTime,f.emit("xhr-done",[t],t),s("xhr",[e,n,this.startTime])}}}function o(t,e){var n=t.responseType;if("json"===n&&null!==e)return e;var r="arraybuffer"===n||"blob"===n||"json"===n?t.response:t.responseText;return h(r)}function i(t,e){var n=c(e),r=t.params;r.host=n.hostname+":"+n.port,r.pathname=n.pathname,t.sameOrigin=n.sameOrigin}var a=t("loader");if(a.xhrWrappable){var s=t("handle"),c=t(16),f=t("ee"),u=["load","error","abort","timeout"],d=u.length,p=t("id"),l=t(19),h=t(18),m=window.XMLHttpRequest;a.features.xhr=!0,t(14),f.on("new-xhr",function(t){var e=this;e.totalCbs=0,e.called=0,e.cbTime=0,e.end=r,e.ended=!1,e.xhrGuids={},e.lastSize=null,l&&(l>34||l<10)||window.opera||t.addEventListener("progress",function(t){e.lastSize=t.loaded},!1)}),f.on("open-xhr-start",function(t){this.params={method:t[0]},i(this,t[1]),this.metrics={}}),f.on("open-xhr-end",function(t,e){"loader_config"in NREUM&&"xpid"in NREUM.loader_config&&this.sameOrigin&&e.setRequestHeader("X-NewRelic-ID",NREUM.loader_config.xpid)}),f.on("send-xhr-start",function(t,e){var n=this.metrics,r=t[0],o=this;if(n&&r){var i=h(r);i&&(n.txSize=i)}this.startTime=a.now(),this.listener=function(t){try{"abort"===t.type&&(o.params.aborted=!0),("load"!==t.type||o.called===o.totalCbs&&(o.onloadCalled||"function"!=typeof e.onload))&&o.end(e)}catch(n){try{f.emit("internal-error",[n])}catch(r){}}};for(var s=0;s<d;s++)e.addEventListener(u[s],this.listener,!1)}),f.on("xhr-cb-time",function(t,e,n){this.cbTime+=t,e?this.onloadCalled=!0:this.called+=1,this.called!==this.totalCbs||!this.onloadCalled&&"function"==typeof n.onload||this.end(n)}),f.on("xhr-load-added",function(t,e){var n=""+p(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&!this.xhrGuids[n]&&(this.xhrGuids[n]=!0,this.totalCbs+=1)}),f.on("xhr-load-removed",function(t,e){var n=""+p(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&this.xhrGuids[n]&&(delete this.xhrGuids[n],this.totalCbs-=1)}),f.on("addEventListener-end",function(t,e){e instanceof m&&"load"===t[0]&&f.emit("xhr-load-added",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),f.on("removeEventListener-end",function(t,e){e instanceof m&&"load"===t[0]&&f.emit("xhr-load-removed",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),f.on("fn-start",function(t,e,n){e instanceof m&&("onload"===n&&(this.onload=!0),("load"===(t[0]&&t[0].type)||this.onload)&&(this.xhrCbStart=a.now()))}),f.on("fn-end",function(t,e){this.xhrCbStart&&f.emit("xhr-cb-time",[a.now()-this.xhrCbStart,this.onload,e],e)})}},{}],16:[function(t,e,n){e.exports=function(t){var e=document.createElement("a"),n=window.location,r={};e.href=t,r.port=e.port;var o=e.href.split("://");!r.port&&o[1]&&(r.port=o[1].split("/")[0].split("@").pop().split(":")[1]),r.port&&"0"!==r.port||(r.port="https"===o[0]?"443":"80"),r.hostname=e.hostname||n.hostname,r.pathname=e.pathname,r.protocol=o[0],"/"!==r.pathname.charAt(0)&&(r.pathname="/"+r.pathname);var i=!e.protocol||":"===e.protocol||e.protocol===n.protocol,a=e.hostname===document.domain&&e.port===n.port;return r.sameOrigin=i&&(!e.hostname||a),r}},{}],17:[function(t,e,n){function r(){}function o(t,e,n){return function(){return i(t,[f.now()].concat(s(arguments)),e?null:this,n),e?void 0:this}}var i=t("handle"),a=t(21),s=t(22),c=t("ee").get("tracer"),f=t("loader"),u=NREUM;"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=u);var d=["setPageViewName","setCustomAttribute","setErrorHandler","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","addRelease"],p="api-",l=p+"ixn-";a(d,function(t,e){u[e]=o(p+e,!0,"api")}),u.addPageAction=o(p+"addPageAction",!0),u.setCurrentRouteName=o(p+"routeName",!0),e.exports=newrelic,u.interaction=function(){return(new r).get()};var h=r.prototype={createTracer:function(t,e){var n={},r=this,o="function"==typeof e;return i(l+"tracer",[f.now(),t,n],r),function(){if(c.emit((o?"":"no-")+"fn-start",[f.now(),r,o],n),o)try{return e.apply(this,arguments)}catch(t){throw c.emit("fn-err",[arguments,this,t],n),t}finally{c.emit("fn-end",[f.now()],n)}}}};a("actionText,setName,setAttribute,save,ignore,onEnd,getContext,end,get".split(","),function(t,e){h[e]=o(l+e)}),newrelic.noticeError=function(t){"string"==typeof t&&(t=new Error(t)),i("err",[t,f.now()])}},{}],18:[function(t,e,n){e.exports=function(t){if("string"==typeof t&&t.length)return t.length;if("object"==typeof t){if("undefined"!=typeof ArrayBuffer&&t instanceof ArrayBuffer&&t.byteLength)return t.byteLength;if("undefined"!=typeof Blob&&t instanceof Blob&&t.size)return t.size;if(!("undefined"!=typeof FormData&&t instanceof FormData))try{return JSON.stringify(t).length}catch(e){return}}}},{}],19:[function(t,e,n){var r=0,o=navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/);o&&(r=+o[1]),e.exports=r},{}],20:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e){if(!o)return!1;if(t!==o)return!1;if(!e)return!0;if(!i)return!1;for(var n=i.split("."),r=e.split("."),a=0;a<r.length;a++)if(r[a]!==n[a])return!1;return!0}var o=null,i=null,a=/Version\/(\S+)\s+Safari/;if(navigator.userAgent){var s=navigator.userAgent,c=s.match(a);c&&s.indexOf("Chrome")===-1&&s.indexOf("Chromium")===-1&&(o="Safari",i=c[1])}e.exports={agent:o,version:i,match:r}},{}],21:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e){var n=[],r="",i=0;for(r in t)o.call(t,r)&&(n[i]=e(r,t[r]),i+=1);return n}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=r},{}],22:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n){e||(e=0),"undefined"==typeof n&&(n=t?t.length:0);for(var r=-1,o=n-e||0,i=Array(o<0?0:o);++r<o;)i[r]=t[e+r];return i}e.exports=r},{}],23:[function(t,e,n){e.exports={exists:"undefined"!=typeof window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&"undefined"!=typeof window.performance.timing.navigationStart}},{}],24:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){return!(t&&t instanceof Function&&t.apply&&!t[a])}var o=t("ee"),i=t(22),a="nr@original",s=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,c=!1;e.exports=function(t,e){function n(t,e,n,o){function nrWrapper(){var r,a,s,c;try{a=this,r=i(arguments),s="function"==typeof n?n(r,a):n||{}}catch(f){p([f,"",[r,a,o],s])}u(e+"start",[r,a,o],s);try{return c=t.apply(a,r)}catch(d){throw u(e+"err",[r,a,d],s),d}finally{u(e+"end",[r,a,c],s)}}return r(t)?t:(e||(e=""),nrWrapper[a]=t,d(t,nrWrapper),nrWrapper)}function f(t,e,o,i){o||(o="");var a,s,c,f="-"===o.charAt(0);for(c=0;c<e.length;c++)s=e[c],a=t[s],r(a)||(t[s]=n(a,f?s+o:o,i,s))}function u(n,r,o){if(!c||e){var i=c;c=!0;try{t.emit(n,r,o,e)}catch(a){p([a,n,r,o])}c=i}}function d(t,e){if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{var n=Object.keys(t);return n.forEach(function(n){Object.defineProperty(e,n,{get:function(){return t[n]},set:function(e){return t[n]=e,e}})}),e}catch(r){p([r])}for(var o in t)s.call(t,o)&&(e[o]=t[o]);return e}function p(e){try{t.emit("internal-error",e)}catch(n){}}return t||(t=o),n.inPlace=f,n.flag=a,n}},{}],ee:[function(t,e,n){function r(){}function o(t){function e(t){return t&&t instanceof r?t:t?c(t,s,i):i()}function n(n,r,o,i){if(!p.aborted||i){t&&t(n,r,o);for(var a=e(o),s=m(n),c=s.length,f=0;f<c;f++)s[f].apply(a,r);var d=u[g[n]];return d&&d.push([b,n,r,a]),a}}function l(t,e){y[t]=m(t).concat(e)}function h(t,e){var n=y[t];if(n)for(var r=0;r<n.length;r++)n[r]===e&&n.splice(r,1)}function m(t){return y[t]||[]}function v(t){return d[t]=d[t]||o(n)}function w(t,e){f(t,function(t,n){e=e||"feature",g[n]=e,e in u||(u[e]=[])})}var y={},g={},b={on:l,addEventListener:l,removeEventListener:h,emit:n,get:v,listeners:m,context:e,buffer:w,abort:a,aborted:!1};return b}function i(){return new r}function a(){(u.api||u.feature)&&(p.aborted=!0,u=p.backlog={})}var s="nr@context",c=t("gos"),f=t(21),u={},d={},p=e.exports=o();p.backlog=u},{}],gos:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n){if(o.call(t,e))return t[e];var r=n();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(t,e,{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(i){}return t[e]=r,r}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=r},{}],handle:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n,r){o.buffer([t],r),o.emit(t,e,n)}var o=t("ee").get("handle");e.exports=r,r.ee=o},{}],id:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){var e=typeof t;return!t||"object"!==e&&"function"!==e?-1:t===window?0:a(t,i,function(){return o++})}var o=1,i="nr@id",a=t("gos");e.exports=r},{}],loader:[function(t,e,n){function r(){if(!E++){var t=x.info=NREUM.info,e=l.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(setTimeout(u.abort,3e4),!(t&&t.licenseKey&&t.applicationID&&e))return u.abort();f(g,function(e,n){t[e]||(t[e]=n)}),c("mark",["onload",a()+x.offset],null,"api");var n=l.createElement("script");n.src="https://"+t.agent,e.parentNode.insertBefore(n,e)}}function o(){"complete"===l.readyState&&i()}function i(){c("mark",["domContent",a()+x.offset],null,"api")}function a(){return O.exists&&performance.now?Math.round(performance.now()):(s=Math.max((new Date).getTime(),s))-x.offset}var s=(new Date).getTime(),c=t("handle"),f=t(21),u=t("ee"),d=t(20),p=window,l=p.document,h="addEventListener",m="attachEvent",v=p.XMLHttpRequest,w=v&&v.prototype;NREUM.o={ST:setTimeout,SI:p.setImmediate,CT:clearTimeout,XHR:v,REQ:p.Request,EV:p.Event,PR:p.Promise,MO:p.MutationObserver};var y=""+location,g={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-spa-1099.min.js"},b=v&&w&&w[h]&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),x=e.exports={offset:s,now:a,origin:y,features:{},xhrWrappable:b,userAgent:d};t(17),l[h]?(l[h]("DOMContentLoaded",i,!1),p[h]("load",r,!1)):(l[m]("onreadystatechange",o),p[m]("onload",r)),c("mark",["firstbyte",s],null,"api");var E=0,O=t(23)},{}]},{},["loader",2,15,5,3,4]);</script><TITLE>Sito Webex Enterprise</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<script language="JavaScript">
function setCookie(name,value) 
{ 
    var Days = 30; 
    var exp = new Date(); 
    exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + Days*24*60*60*1000); 
    document.cookie = name + "="+ escape (value) + ";expires=" + exp.toGMTString()+";path=/"; 
} 


function getCookie(Name)
{


    var search = Name + "=";
    if (document.cookie.length > 0)
    { // if there are any cookies
        offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search);
        if (offset != -1)
        { // if cookie exists
            offset += search.length; // set index of beginning of value
             end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset); // set index of end of cookie value
             if (end == -1)
                 end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end));
        }
    }
}
  //default page should never load inside of another frame
  if (top.location != self.location) {
    top.location = self.location;
  }



var oneDay= 1*24*60*60*1000;
var expDate = new Date();
expDate.setTime (expDate.getTime() + oneDay);
var cookieExpires = expDate.toGMTString();

document.cookie="verifyCookie=test; expires="+cookieExpires

if (document.cookie.length<=0 || getCookie("verifyCookie") == null){
    window.open('https://campus.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/jsp/common/warningnote.jsp?siteurl=campus', 'Warning', 'toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no,scrollbars=auto,resizable=yes,width=300,height=220');
}

document.cookie="verifyCookie=CLEAR; expires=Sun, 09-Nov-97 01:00:00 GMT";
try{
    if('&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;loginframe.do&#63;siteurl&#61;campus&#38;rnd&#61;0.8746987491314661'.indexOf("meetinginfo")!=-1||( '&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;loginframe.do&#63;siteurl&#61;campus&#38;rnd&#61;0.8746987491314661'.indexOf("e.do")!=-1&&'&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;loginframe.do&#63;siteurl&#61;campus&#38;rnd&#61;0.8746987491314661'.indexOf("siteurl")!=-1)&&'&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;loginframe.do&#63;siteurl&#61;campus&#38;rnd&#61;0.8746987491314661'.indexOf("landingpage.do")==-1&&'&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;loginframe.do&#63;siteurl&#61;campus&#38;rnd&#61;0.8746987491314661'.indexOf("mainframe.do")==-1&&'&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;loginframe.do&#63;siteurl&#61;campus&#38;rnd&#61;0.8746987491314661'.indexOf("mywebex")==-1&&'&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;loginframe.do&#63;siteurl&#61;campus&#38;rnd&#61;0.8746987491314661'.indexOf("frame.do")==-1){
        setCookie("jmtlogloginclicktime",new Date().getTime());
    }
}catch(ex){

}


    var dom = document.getElementById ? 1 : 0;
    var ns4 = (document.layers && !dom ) ? 1 : 0;
    // do for ns4 resize problem
    function mm_reloadPage(init) {  //reloads the window if Nav4 resized
        if (init==true) {
            with (navigator) {
                if ((appName=="Netscape") && (parseInt(appVersion)==4)) {
                    document.mm_pgW=innerWidth;
                    document.mm_pgH=innerHeight;
                    onresize=mm_reloadPage;
                }
            }
        } else if (innerWidth!=document.mm_pgW || innerHeight!=document.mm_pgH) {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
    if(ns4)
        mm_reloadPage(true);


document.cookie = "screenWidth=" + screen.width + "; path=/; secure";

function closeWindow() {
    window.close(opener=0);
}
function submitChildFrame(){
    window.frames["mainFrame"].postChildForm("\x2fmw3300\x2fmywebex\x2floginframe.do\x3fsiteurl\x3dcampus\x26rnd\x3d0.8746987491314661");
}
function submitChildFrame4Header(){
    window.frames["header"].postChildForm4Logout();
}
</script>


<base href="https://campus.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/jsp/frame/mywebex.jsp">
</HEAD>

<!-- CDN Host: akamaicdn.webex.com Status: OK -->

<FRAMESET id="topframeset" BORDER=0 FRAMEBORDER=0 FRAMESPACING=0 ROWS="131,*,0">
    <FRAME SCROLLING="auto"  NORESIZE NAME="header" SRC="/mw3300/mywebex/header.do?service=10&siteurl=campus&rnd=0.513406995989277" title="The header frame of Cisco WebEx Meetings">


        <FRAME SCROLLING="auto" NORESIZE NAME="mainFrame" SRC="&#47;mw3300&#47;mywebex&#47;loginframe.do&#63;siteurl&#61;campus&#38;rnd&#61;0.8746987491314661" target="_top" title="The content frame of Cisco WebEx Meetings">

    <FRAME SCROLLING="no"  NORESIZE NAME="rotation" SRC="/mw3300/mywebex/frame/clientpath.do?siteurl=campus" title="The clientPath frame of Cisco WebEx Meetings">
</FRAMESET>



<noframes>
<h2>Spiacenti.</h2>
&nbsp;<p><b>Webex richiede l'uso di Netscape Navigator 4.0, Internet Explorer 4.0 o versioni successive.</b></p>
</noframes>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the By module:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.theurl.com") 
browser.find_element(By.NAME,"userName").send_keys("Test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. Lukas's solution works fine ed I log in. But I don't understand why it works only for the link you used. In fact if I use this other link "https://campus.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/default.do?siteurl=campus&service=7", that I need 'cos there are more functions, It doesn't work! the same code doesn't work! Why???
I switched to Python 2.7 but there are some ASCII problems.... Maybe this the reason??

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
delay = 100  # seconds

browser.get("https://campus.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/default.do?siteurl=campus&service=7")
myelem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'mwx-ipt-username')))
utente = browser.find_element_by_id("mwx-ipt-username").send_keys('User')
psw = browser.find_element_by_id("mwx-ipt-password").send_keys('Psw')
myelem.submit()
```

but this code doesn't find the elements... why??

bye